# Hadith authenticity - Abu Dawud - Adam children , divine decree?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

Is this hadith in sunan abi dawud authentic? Please can you provide sources of the muhaddith and their gradings, al albani says its sahih except the wiping of the back? Link is below.

https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4703

Comment: Does this help: https://dorar.net/hadith/sharh/113261 and shorturl.at/vAKO4 ?